# Accessing file association information from shell in macOS Sonoma (14.3.1)

Tags: macos, zsh, file-association, macos-sonoma

macOS used to use a plist at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist` to store file association information. Recently(ish) that file has moved and is now called `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist`.

However under macOS Sonoma (14.3.1) it seems that even that has now been superseded.

So though I can change file associations through the usual Finder route, how can I access/update file association information from the command line?

Specifically, I'd like to write a zsh utility that switches the default application used for MP4 files between Quicktime Player and Lossless Cut. Something like:

```
If default Application for mp4 is Quicktime Player set to Lossless Cut and vice versa.
```

But I can't find any command(s) that would allow me to do this.

So I need to know where the file association information is now stored and what commands allow you to manipulate that information.

And in case you are wondering why I'd like to do this I frequently (several times a day) switch between opening mp4s in Quicktime Player and Lossless Cut. Usually it is different files and so a solution changing the file association for a given file wouldn't be that helpful (though others may find that answer of assistance).